# Half the Bounty? Is that possible?

Tags: bounties, support, auto-acceptance, specific-question

Okay, so [my answer has just been accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845913/creating-picture-gallery/1859279#1859279) on a 100 bounty question but somehow I just got 50 bounty points, why is that?

It's not that I care that much about the reputation, it's just that SO has lots of mysterious / obscure behaviors and I feel like I don't know them at all. Can someone clarify this one for me please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question owner did not select your answer. It was auto-selected (at least 2 upvotes and posted after the bounty). If it is auto-selected, you only get half of the bounty.

Any existing answers before the start of the bounty  are not eligible to win via auto-acceptance. Only those posted after and with +2 are.

Your answer was among others on a level footing of +2 upvotes. But, as yours was posted first, it was auto-accepted as the bounty winner.

Comment: But this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845913/creating-picture-gallery/1845939#1845939) had more up votes than mine did. Why was my answer selected and not his?

Comment: Oh I get it... Posted after the bounty. Thanks!