# Bounty received of 50?

Tags: support, bounties, auto-acceptance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Half the Bounty? Is that possible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32820/half-the-bounty-is-that-possible)

I just received a bounty of 50 rep today, but I thought the minimum was 100; 50 from the poster and 50 from the site.  I wasn't near the rep cap, so that's not it.  What's up?

[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/761/bounty.png](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/761/bounty.png)

Comment: Auto accepted bounties get 1/2 the bounty.

Comment: @ChrisF - post that as the answer - it's the answer!

Comment: @ChrisF, I didn't have the most votes, so how could my answer have been auto-accepted?

Comment: See this answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067

Comment: @Dominic - the question is a duplicate (effectively). I've only just found the relevant question

Comment: @Lance - auto acceptance only happens for answers posted after the bounty starts. So the other answers were posted earlier.

Comment: @ChrisF, thanks, I see that now in the FAQ, learn something new every day.

Comment: Hey guys, I found the exact dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32820/half-the-bounty-is-that-possible, and voted to close.

Comment: @dom, it's not good etiquette to answer a duplicate question. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40316

Comment: @dom, that's incorrect, IT IS good etiquette to answer all questions, please don't be buffaloed.

Comment: I'd post this as an answer, but the question is closed.  Now that the bounty system has been revamped, it is possible for a bounty's full value to be 50 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> The highest voted answer created after
>   the bounty started with at least 2
>   upvotes will be automatically
>   accepted. Half the bounty will be
>   awarded to the owner of that answer.

Comment: yes, but I didn't have the most votes, or even the second-most

Comment: @Lance - the important bit is **created after the bounty started**