# Cannot mark accepted answer for one of my questions

Tags: support, specific-question, accepted-answer

So I noticed my accepted answer rate went to 79% on SO. I went to mark answers on a couple of ancient questions that never got answered properly.

However, for one of these I cannot mark an answer.

The question in question is [Using canvas to grab pixel data from page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181208/using-canvas-to-grab-pixel-data-from-page)

What does one do when this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set a 150 point [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) in the past that has now lapsed.

The question failed to get any new answers with **+2** which would have been eligible for half the bounty on offer under [auto-accept conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32820/half-the-bounty-is-that-possible).

Since you also did not check the mark before the close of the bounty period, you can now [**no longer** check any answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty) in future.

Comment: Looks like the bounty was set on **2010-02-03**

Comment: Ah yes indeed, I forgot about the bounty. So its not possible to accept even after the bounty expires? Interesting

Comment: @Darko: *Only* after the bounty expires, it's not possible to accept.